# problems with a particular Json, cant Convert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Is there a way to get only a part of a json ?, I need (Entity) and then send it to the view, I have tried to convert it in different ways without success, please help.

JSON - i dont need Statuscode and Message, Entity is the real data

```
{"StatusCode":200,"Message":"succesfull list.","Entity":"[{\"Name\":\"name 1\",\"Enable\":1,\"Celphone\":null},{\"Name\":\"name 2\",\"Enable\":1,\"Celphone\":\"0\"}]"}
```

Model

```
public class Root
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
 var clientsEntity= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
 return View(clientsEntity);
```

error:

> The model element passed to the dictionary is of type 'APP.Models.Root', pbut this dictionary requires a model element of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[APP.Models.EntityModel]'.

I even tried creating an extra class

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public string Celphone { get; set; }
}

 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, Object>>>(clientsEntity.Entity); //data has data needed
 returnView(data);
```

error:

> The model element passed to the dictionary is of type'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]', but this dictionary requires a model element of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[APP.Models.EntityModel]'.

I have tried many more ways, but I am stuck and out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is double serialized.  To handle it, you first need to deserialize the JSON to your `Root` class, then deserialize the `Entity` property of that to a `List<Entity>`.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
var entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(root.Entity);
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jjbFNc

Comment: Based on OP's words "I even tried creating an extra class" I'm not sure that this will solve the issue - it will depend on which `Entity` type is actually available in the place where deserialization is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly determined that your json is double serialized and you need to deserialize it's `Entity` property second time, but you have used wrong type for that attempt.

The error you are having means that view expects model of `IEnumerable<APP.Models.EntityModel>` type (which is declared via something like `@model IEnumerable<APP.Models.EntityModel>` at the top of the view), but you are actually passing it a model of different type (`Root` in the first attempt and `IEnumerable` of dictionaries in the second). So you need either change model which view is expecting or deserialize to correct type. For second one you can try next:

```cs
 var clientsEntity= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<APP.Models.EntityModel>>(clientsEntity.Entity);
 returnView(data);
```

Comment: this works to, i am going to investigate the diference between a list and IEnumerable, and validate which one would work better in my application

Comment: @LuisEduardoB there should be big difference. Probably json library internally even will use lists to represent `IEnumerable`s